# Integral sections of higher order jet fields

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, fiber-bundles, jet-bundles

Let us consider a bundle $(E,\pi, M)$ and let $k\in \mathbb N$. I am going to adopt the notations and conventions by Saunders.

**Preliminaries**

A *first-order jet field* on $\pi$ is a section of the bundle $(J^1\pi,\pi_0^1, E)$, $\pi_0^1$ being the target projection, i.e. $\pi_0^1(j^1_m\phi)=\phi(m)$. More generally, a *$k$-th order jet field* on $\pi$ is a section of the bundle $(J^k\pi, \pi_{k-1}^k, J^{k-1}\pi)$, $\pi_{k-1}^k$ being the projection $j^k_m\phi\mapsto j^{k-1}_m\phi$ (Actually, Saunders gives only the definitions for $k=1,2$).

A first-order jet field $X$ on $\pi$ is termed *integrable* if there is a local section $\psi$ of $\pi$ such that $X\circ \psi=j^1\psi$. Such a section is called an *integral section* of $X$.

There is a canonical embedding:
$$
\iota_{k}\colon j^{k}_m\phi\in J^{k}\pi\to j^{1}_m(j^{k-1} \phi)\in J^1(\pi_{k-1})\,,
$$
where $\pi_{k-1}\colon J^{k-1} \pi\to M$ is the $(k-1)$-source projection on $\pi$, i.e. $\pi_{k-1}(j^{k-1}_m\phi)=m$.

**Question**
Let  $X$ be a $k$-th order jet field on $\pi$. Then $X_k=\iota_k\circ X$ is a first-order jet field on $\pi_{k-1}$.

If $X_k$ is integrable and $\psi$ is an integral section of $X_k$, are there local section $\phi$ of $\pi$ such that $\psi=j^{k-1}\phi$? (Saunders proves it only for $k=2$ on page 181).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I found my answer in Saunders's PhD thesis.